# Creating a Main Application only if another app doesn't exists

Tags: android

I want to create an icon on the application drawer only if another application of mine (same developer) is not exists. 
When I add the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER to the xml, the icon always appear.

For example:
One app of mine create 3 icons on the drawer application and another app create one icon that is the same of 1 of the 3 from the first app.
I want the first app to check whether the second app is installed and only then decide to create only the 2 or 3 icons.

Is any way that it can be done?

Thank you all from ahead ! =)

Comment: u mean u dont want your application to be installed on a phone if it already have you application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect if other apps of your are installed then hide the icon:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Note that the icon may not be gone until the next reboot.

Comment: There is any way to remove the icon before the next reboot?

Comment: Simple answer: no. (but depending on the laucher it may disappear before next reboot. There is nothing you can do to change that.